# django-import-export empty rows before csv header trigger exception while importing

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

While importing data from csv, I realized that this error is triggered if the first row is not the header

`list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

```
first_name,last_name,email,password,role
Noak,Larrett,nlarrett0@ezinearticles.com,8sh15apPjI,Student
Duffie,Milesap,dmilesap1@wikipedia.org,bKNIlIWVfNw,Student
```

It only works if the first row is the header

```
first_name,last_name,email,password,role
Noak,Larrett,nlarrett0@ezinearticles.com,8sh15apPjI,Student
Duffie,Milesap,dmilesap1@wikipedia.org,bKNIlIWVfNw,Student

...
```

I tried overwriting `before_import` to remove any blank row

```
def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
    indexes = []
    for i in range(0, len(dataset)):
        row = ''.join(dataset[i])
        if row.strip() == '':
            indexes.append(i)
    for index in sorted(indexes, reverse=True):
        del dataset[index]          
    return dataset
```

This works for all the rows, except the first row which should always contain the header, and if not the error is thrown.

Comment: I've seen this. Why not just remove the empty rows before importing (manually)?

Comment: Because it's the user that will be importing data and I just want Python to automatically take care of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I found the `ImportMixin` class, which is in `import_export/admin.py`

The class contains a method called `import_action` that looks like this

```
def import_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    import_file = form.cleaned_data['import_file']
    ...
    data = tmp_storage.read(input_format.get_read_mode())
    ...
    dataset = input_format.create_dataset(data)
    ...
```

As you can see, this is the function that reads the uploaded file to a string before passing it to `input_format.create_dataset()`. So all I had to do was adding a custom function that removed the blank lines

```
data = self.remove_blanks(data)
dataset = input_format.create_dataset(data)
```

**import_export/admin.py/ImportMixin**

```
def remove_blanks(self, data):
    return os.linesep.join([s for s in data.splitlines() if s.strip()])
```

This way any csv file will not have any blank line, which will force the first line to be the header and that solves the problem. I hope this will be useful to anyone facing the same issue.

**UPDATE** : There is also an easy way to do the same by overwriting `create_dataset` in `import_export/formats/base_formats.py`

**import_export/formats/base_formats.py/TablibFormat**

```
def create_dataset(self, in_stream, **kwargs):
    in_stream = os.linesep.join([s for s in in_stream.splitlines() if s.strip()])
    try:
        return tablib.import_set(in_stream, format=self.get_title())
    except:
        return tablib.import_set('', format=self.get_title())
```